# What is the name of Wikipedia programming type?

Tags: mediawiki, wiki, wikipedia, dokuwiki, wikimedia

I am a CMS programmer and I created a CMS what work like Wikipedia, I mean each link can have parent and children pages.

In Wikipedia there are a link and that link has some children and each children link has some children and all of them has parent too and so on.

**Is this kind of programming named three system?**

*(I did't know what tags should add for this question)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wikipedia pages are stored as web pages, not an internal data structure in memory/RAM like a linked list. The "links" are just links to other pages. A link to a "parent" is simply another HTML link to another page, it is not a parent in the sense of a data structure might make you believe. The "links" in Wikipedia are just turned into HTML links before being displayed in your browser.

Why did you recreate another Content Management System? There are several free wiki software packages out there already. My annoyance with wikis is their markup language varies a bit from package to package

These lists should get you started. Surely you can find one for your OS.

- [Free wiki software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Free_wiki_software)
- [Comparison of wiki software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_wiki_software)
- [10 Free Wiki Software Platforms](http://www.clickonf5.org/7599/10-free-opensource-wiki-software-engine/)
- [Best wiki software compared](http://www.siteground.com/compare_best_wiki.htm). With pie graph showing market share on Siteground servers. (These are hosting companies only.)

Comment: OH NO! I know tree system programming and just needs to know is the name of wikipedia system tree or no! drupal has a maduel what named book. and works well